# Basemap with joint histograms plot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, histogram, matplotlib-basemap

Here is the code returning the figure below:

```
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
gs = plt.GridSpec(3, 3)
ax_main = plt.subplot(gs[1:3, :2])
ax_lon = plt.subplot(gs[0, :2])
ax_lat = plt.subplot(gs[1:3, 2])

m = Basemap(projection='merc', resolution='i', llcrnrlon=llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat=llcrnrlat,
            urcrnrlon=urcrnrlon, urcrnrlat=urcrnrlat, ax=ax_main)

try:
    m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
except:
    pass
m.drawcountries()
m.drawmapboundary()

lon_range = urcrnrlon - llcrnrlon
lat_range = urcrnrlat - llcrnrlat
lat_interval = round(0.2 * lat_range, 2)
lon_interval = round(0.2 * lon_range, 2)

parallels = np.arange(-90, 90, lat_interval)
meridians = np.arange(-180, 180, lon_interval)
m.drawparallels(parallels, labels=[0, 1, 0, 0], fontsize=8, dashes=[1, 5])
m.drawmeridians(meridians, labels=[0, 0, 1, 0], fontsize=8, dashes=[1, 5])
m.fillcontinents(color='#F0F0F0', lake_color='#F0F0F0')

x1, y1 = m(LON_1, LAT_1)
x2, y2 = m(LON_2, LAT_2)

ax_main.scatter(x1, y1, c='steelblue', alpha=.8,  s=8, label='Data 1')
ax_main.scatter(x2, y2, c='red', alpha=.8, s=8, label='Data 2')
ax_main.set_xlabel('Longitude', fontsize=12, labelpad=10)
ax_main.set_ylabel('Latitude', fontsize=12, labelpad=10)
ax_main.legend(loc='upper right') 

# Histogram of longitude
ax_lon.hist(LON_1, bins=20, histtype='step', density=True, color='steelblue', 
            align='mid', label='Data 1')
ax_lon.hist(LON_2, bins=20, histtype='step', density=True, color='red', 
            align='mid', label='Data2')
ax_lon.set_xticks([]) 
ax_lon.set_yticks([]) 
#ax_lon.legend(loc='upper right')

# Histogram of latitude
ax_lat.hist(LAT_1, bins=20, histtype='step', density=True, color='steelblue', align='mid', 
            orientation='horizontal', label='Data 1')
ax_lat.hist(LAT_2, bins=20, histtype='step', density=True, color='red', align='mid', 
            orientation='horizontal', label='Data 2')
# ax_lat.tick_params(axis='y', rotation=-90)
ax_lat.set_yticks([]) 
ax_lat.set_xticks([]) 
#ax_lat.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

I cannot adjust the histograms' size with sharex/sharey option otherwise they are not properly displayed (do not know why, but I think it has to do with Basemap).
Is there a way to adjust the top histogram size such that its x-axis (y-axis) is the same as the x-axis (y-axis) of the map (right histo)?